# Counting sequences in a file beginning and ending with a user defined match

Tags: regex, perl, fasta

I have a fasta formatted file of DNA sequences called "test.fas":

```
>test1
GCCATTACAGAACATCAGTCACAGTACGTACTGTGTTCTGCCGTGCTGTCTA
>test2
CGGATGAAGCGCCAATCGTACGTACAATAAGTTGCCTAAAGTGTTTCA
>test3
ATGCATGCATGC
```

I also have a file of tab delimited primer sequences called "primers.txt":

```
GCCATTACAGAACATCAGTCACA TAGACAGCACGGCAGAACAC
CGGATGAAGCGCCAATC   TGAAACACTTTAGGCAACTTATT
```

Each line in this primers.txt file is a primer pair that may match the start and end of a sequence in the fasta file. The second primer on each line also needs to be reverse complemented before it would match anything in the fasta file. Looking at the first primer pair on the first line in primers.txt, after reverse complementing the second primer, it should match the sequence for test1 in the test.fas file.

What I want to be able to do is supply these two files to a perl program, and get an output file of counts for how many times a sequence was found with a primer pair from the primers.txt file. In this case, my outfile would list:

```
1
1
```

In reality I have 650000 sequences in a file, and 170 primer sets to search for and enumerate from the file. Therefore, I want an outfile 170 lines long, with each line listing the number of times a match was found in the fasta file for that specific primer pair. Basically, for each line in the primer.txt file, count the number of times a sequence shows up in the fasta file that begins and ends with that primer pair.  This is what I have come up with so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Name of the FASTA file: ";
chomp( my $multifasta = <STDIN> );

print "Name file with primers: ";
chomp( my $pulls = <STDIN> );

print "Name of the output file: ";
chomp( my $out = <STDIN> );

open(MULTIFASTA,$multifasta) || die ;
  my $seq = do { local $/; <MULTIFASTA>};
  close MULTIFASTA;

open(PULLS,$pulls) || die;
  while (my $line = <PULLS>){
  chomp $line;
  my @primers = split (/\t/,$line);
  my $revcomp = reverse $primers[1];
  $revcomp =~ tr/ATGCatgc/TACGtacg/;  #reverse complement the reverse primer
  my $matches = () = $seq =~ /^\Q$primers[0].*\Q$primers[1]$/; #How to structure the regex? 
  open(OUTFILE,">>$out");
  print OUTFILE "$matches\n";   
}
```

My outfile ends up with this:

```
0
0
```

I obviously have something screwed up. I am rapidly falling in the trap of trying different things I find on Google without having a firm grasp of what that is doing to the code, and at this point I am lost. That is a consequence of really needing the answer soon, and knowing very little about programming.  I gathered from reading that I should be reading in the whole file to scan for matches in with local, and I need to use \Q to search for a variable in a regex in perl. Anyway, any help or pointers would be very much appreciated. Thanks -

Comment: (1) If the "_reverse complemented_" one should match then you want `$revcomp` in the regex, not `$primers[1]` (2) Open the file before the `while` loop, and (within one run of the program) you don't need the append mode (`>>`) but rather just `>` (3) No need for `\Q`, but you do need `/gm` modifiers (without `/m the `^` and `$` match the whole string's start and end, not individual lines); you also want `.*` to be `.*?`.  So: `/^$primers[0].*?$revcomp$/mg`   // With these changes it works for me (with sample input you provide)

Comment: Ah, I can't believe I forgot to put $revcomp in place of $primers[1]. Incorporating your suggestions, it works now for me too. Thank you!

Comment: yeah, I thought it was a blunder -- it happens :)  Note that you read a half-million-sequence file right into a variable .. like 50Mb? It works but it is something to be acutely aware of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a regex from all the primers. Also, store the primers in a hash, the values will be the line numbers. Then, iterate over the fasta file and try to match the regex. If it matches, use the hash to retrieve the line number of the primer and use another hash to record the number of matches per line number. At the end, just report the numbers:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($fasta_file, $primers_file) = @ARGV;

my %primer;
open my $primers_fh, '<', $primers_file or die $!;
while (<$primers_fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($first, $second) = split /\t/;
    $second = reverse $second;
    $second =~ tr/actgACTG/tgacTGAC/;
    undef $primer{$first}{$.};
    undef $primer{$second}{$.};
}

my $primers_count = $.;
my $regex =  join '|', keys %primer;

my %seen;
open my $fasta_fh, '<', $fasta_file or die $!;
while (<$fasta_fh>) {
    if (/^($regex)/) {
        ++$seen{$_} for keys %{ $primer{$1} };
    }
}

for my $line_number (sort { $a <=> $b } 1 .. $primers_count) {
    print $seen{$line_number} // 0, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Can you clarify what the 'undef' does please?

Comment: See [undef](http://p3rl.org/undef). In this case, it just creates a key in the hash with no value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what `\Q` (and `\E`) does. It's for backslashing regex special characters automatically. It is not for "searching for a variable in a regex". Perl already recognizes variables in regexes natively. You don't need `\Q` here.

```
my $matches = () = $seq =~ /^\Q$primers[0].*\Q$primers[1]$/;
```

A basic regex match like this returns 1 or 0 for true and false. It does not return you an array of matches like you want it to. You need the `g` global modifier for that.

You probably also need the `.*` to be non-greedy here using `.*?` instead.

You also are using `^` and `$` incorrectly here. This forces your primers to match only at the start and end of the (multi-line) string rather than for lines within it. That's why you are getting 0 (false) for your matches.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about \Q,  \E, as well as the "g" global modifier. In this case, I actually do want the primers to match exactly at the start and end of the sequences and exclude everything else, because only those sequences are my target amplicons.

Comment: suggest to add a statement on how to fix anchors (see [`/m` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#OPERATORS) ) and then to offer a fixed, working, regex